# Mock Static Enum Inside Final Class

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

there is a class X;

```
public final class X {
    private X() {}
    ...
    public static enum E {
        thingA("1"),
        thingB("0")

        public boolean isEnabled(){...}
    }
    ...
}
```

in some another class there a method M

```
public class AnotherClass{

    public void M(){
        if (E.thingB.isEnabled()) {
            doSomething();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

i want to test M method, is it possible to use mockito/powermockito to
mock statement within if. to do something like this

```
 when(E.thingB.isEnabled()).thenReturn(true)?
```

Comment: Did you try it yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of whether the enum is nested or not, you can't create or mock a new instance of an enum. [Enums are implicitly final](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9), and more importantly, it breaks the assumption that all instances of the enum are declared within the enum.

> An enum type has no instances other than those defined by its enum constants. It is a compile-time error to attempt to explicitly instantiate an enum type. ([JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9))

Because all instances of the enum are known at compile time, and all properties of those instances are likewise predictable, **usually you can just pass in an instance that matches your needs without mocking anything**. If you want to accept an arbitrary instance with those properties, have your enum implement an interface instead.

```
public interface I {
    boolean isEnabled();
}

public enum E implements I {  // By the way, all enums are necessarily static.
    thingA("1"),
    thingB("0");

    public boolean isEnabled(){...}
}
```